# How to send notification to registered users of same application in android

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-notifications

I want to notify the users who have downloaded application, whenever something added by me as a administrator.

Each user downloaded the application will register. I have all the info about the users.

I want to notify when something added to my application ( Usually data i added will be stored in database).

Please give me idea how to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to send messages to the users who installed your application, you must have a server. You have the following options,

**1. Google cloud messaging**

You can send push notifications to your users Via GCM saying like "New update available" or something.

You can use Google Appengine for server and it is free. There is an open source project for GCM integration http://gcm4public.appspot.com/

**2. Parse SDK**

You can use Parse SDK for Push notifications & Online data. You dont need to do any server side coding if you are using Parse SDK. You can use Parse for Social media login, Registration, Online score, data, Push notifications etc..

[Parse SDK](https://parse.com/)

**3. If you own a server for notifying update refer this,**

http://www.androidsnippets.com/check-for-updates-once-a-day

**4. If you can put the updated changes in a text file and uploaded in Dropbox like online storage then refer this,**

[Android-WVersionManager](https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WVersionManager)

**5. If you just wanted to check whether new version is available on google play use the following function (Note:- Dont forget to add Jsoup library)**

```
private boolean isNewVersionReleasedONGooglePlay(){
    try {       
    String currentVersion = applicationContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(package_name, 0).versionName; 
    String newVersion = currentVersion;
    newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + package_name + "&hl=en")
            .timeout(30000)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
            .referrer("http://www.google.com")
            .get()
            .select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]")
            .first()
            .ownText();
    return (value(currentVersion) < value(newVersion)) ? true : false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
    }
}
```

**6. For more information have a look into Apptentive & Turkcell SDK**

[Apptentive SDK](https://github.com/apptentive/apptentive-android)

[TurkcellUpdater](https://github.com/Turkcell/TurkcellUpdater_android_sdk)

Comment: I have seen so many tutorials where they show how to push notifications through server, but i wanted to push from my android app, whenever i add new data it must notify like new event added.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) for push notification.
You can follow [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) for GCM push notification.

Comment: i have seen this tut before, it shows how to push from web console, but i want it to be done, when something updated from app.

Comment: okay. so when you update something in your app will notify the web or what?

Comment: it must notify the registered users of my application.

Comment: yeah agree with that. but if you update something in your app then it should notify the web and the web will notify all the registered users via push notification. Is it something like that?

Comment: i need some tuts for server side code, If u know any pls post link here

Comment: its up to your requirements for choosing server side. but if you go for java then you may refer this getting started tutorial.
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077634/java-web-development/how-to-get-started-with-server-side-java.html

Comment: If you are going with php for server side coding then I have already added the link for GCM tutorial in my answer.