# Notification to android without GCM

Tags: php, android, notifications

I have a android application on PlayStore. I used  PHP and MySql for sending data to android.  I want to send notification to all users who downloaded our application .I don's want to use GCM for notification.Is there any method to do it?

Comment: I am not sure why you do not want to use GCM. You can use parse SDK. If you don't want that too, then you will have to make your own notification class, methods etc that will check if there is a new notification in database and then display that as notification, that would not be easy to implement

Comment: Upon first download, with-in application you can call a custom created web-service which return notification data and then can display it using NotificationManager. but i'll recommend you to use GCM

Comment: This question should be marked as a duplicate. It has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979045/how-to-send-notification-to-registered-users-of-same-application-in-android). And answered very well too.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all the answers you can find aren't real answers. Parse, pushwosh, Amazon SNS and many more use GCM at their core. Yes there are reasons not to use GCM e.g. if developing an SDK that needs easy integration into apps that aren't under your control. https://pushy.me/ is one of the very few I found so far that doesn't use GCM at all.

I also found this: https://docs.kii.com/en/samples/push-notifications/push-notifications-jpush/ but unfortunately there's nothing about pricing.

Answer (score 0):

There are many third party libraries out there such as urban airship, amazon sns etc. 
See this

http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android.html and this
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html

Comment: Both are using GCM at their core so this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pushwoosh` SDK to send notification.
http://docs.pushwoosh.com/

Comment: Pushwoosh is using GCM at its core so this doesn't answer the question.