# Android synchronize data between different devices on Same app

Tags: java, android, synchronize

Im planning to develop an android app which allows the user to add different items to a List. My goal is to display every new added item immediately to an User with the Same app on a different device.

Im looking for a good approach without using any server to store the data. Now i know there are syncadaper but im not quite sure how to apply this concept to my use case. Basically a solution similar to a chat peogram is what a have in mind.

I already did my research but couldnt find a good fitting  answer.

So i would appreciate any Suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979045/how-to-send-notification-to-registered-users-of-same-application-in-android where your data can be inside the notification

Comment: Perhaps using Firebase Database would suit your needs https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Comment: Firebase seems to be a very nice solution/approach. I will give it a try after my concept is done and going to give a feedback. Thanks

Comment: Due to certain circumstances... I wont use any cloud based system, rather I will set up a webserver (maybe on a pi or sth. similar) containing a webservice and a database. I will try to sync the device with the server using the android sync adapter.